# how can I collect data from a user through bot

Tags: c#, .net, azure-sql-database, botframework

I need to collect some data from a user, through bot that uses microsoft bot framework and store those data in a Azure database? anyone can help with proper code examples and links? Thanks in advance.

***Requirements***: need to ask from a particular user, his nsme, email address and phone number and store them in a data base.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you googled this? There are enough resource out there for the task you want to accomplish. Show us what have you tried. Then ask for something specific. Otherwise its very difficult to help.

Comment: `collect some data from a user, through bot that uses microsoft bot framework and store those data in a Azure database` What's the data you want to collect? Something like username&password etc, user specific information? If you'd like to exchange user specific information between client and bot, [the backchannel mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel) would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @BhashithaHemantha, any updates? Please clarify your requirement and question.

Comment: @FeiHan actually I just need to ask from a particular user, his nsme, email address and phone number and store them in a data base.

Comment: @BhashithaHemantha, I shared a sample that can help collect user information, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just need to ask from a particular user, his nsme, email address and phone number and store them in a data base

To achieve this requirement, you can refer to the following sample code to collect user information.

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    string name;
    string email;
    string phone;

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        if (activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("ok"))
        {
            PromptDialog.Text(
                context: context,
                resume: ResumeGetName,
                prompt: "Please share your name",
                retry: "Please try again."
            );
        }
        else
        {
            context.Done(this);
        }

        //context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public async Task ResumeGetName(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> Username)
    {
        string uname = await Username;
        name = uname;

        PromptDialog.Text(
            context: context,
            resume: ResumeGetEmail,
            prompt: "Please share your Email",
            retry: "Please try again."
        );
    }

    public async Task ResumeGetEmail(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> UserEmail)
    {
        string uemail = await UserEmail;
        email = uemail; 

        PromptDialog.Text(
            context: context,
            resume: ResumeGetPhone,
            prompt: "Please share your Phone Number",
            retry: "Please try again."
        );
    }
    public async Task ResumeGetPhone(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> mobile)
    {
        string response = await mobile;
        phone = response;

        //in this Resume handler, you can save the data that you collected from user into your sql database

        await context.PostAsync($"your name:{name}, email:{email}, phonenumber: {phone}");

        context.Done(this);
    }
}
```

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you...so instead of printing out the user details, I should just do a post request to store the collected data to a database. right?

Comment: Yes, you should write the code to insert data into your database. [This artilce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio) shows how to access Azure SQL database via ADO.NET, you can refer to it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use a bot to collect information from a user. On the development of bot exists the concept of form which allow us to create a flow of question to the user. The SQL side will be managed as we are used to do with C#, a connection string along with an INSERT statement. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow) you will find documentation about forms. These are two samples using forms: [(1)](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) and [(2)](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs).

Basically you create an entity with the fields you need to collect data. With this we create the form flow and with the entity the bot will ask for the information to the user. It will show options and present a final summary.

The following code shows you how to connect to SQL Azure Database using C#:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;   // System.Data.dll 
//using System.Data;           // For:  SqlDbType , ParameterDirection

namespace csharp_db_test
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         try
         {
            var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            cb.DataSource = "your_server.database.windows.net";
            cb.UserID = "your_user";
            cb.Password = "your_password";
            cb.InitialCatalog = "your_database";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString))
            {
               connection.Open();

               Submit_Tsql_NonQuery(connection, "2 - Create-Tables",
                  Build_2_Tsql_CreateTables());

               Submit_Tsql_NonQuery(connection, "3 - Inserts",
                  Build_3_Tsql_Inserts());

               Submit_Tsql_NonQuery(connection, "4 - Update-Join",
                  Build_4_Tsql_UpdateJoin(),
                  "@csharpParmDepartmentName", "Accounting");

               Submit_Tsql_NonQuery(connection, "5 - Delete-Join",
                  Build_5_Tsql_DeleteJoin(),
                  "@csharpParmDepartmentName", "Legal");

               Submit_6_Tsql_SelectEmployees(connection);
            }
         }
         catch (SqlException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
         }
         Console.WriteLine("View the report output here, then press any key to end the program...");
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-first-database-csharp) you will find more information about how to connect to SQL Azure from C#.